# Bootstrap. Как текстовое поле выровнять по всей ширине в td?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

bootstrap. 
Как текстовое поле выровнять по всей ширине в td?

```
<td><input type="text"></td>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Использовать стандартную bootstrap форму и поля
2. Задать полю ширину в 100% - `class="w-100"`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
  
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="w-100" placeholder="Текстовое поле">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```